# How should I generate a "secret" code for my two factor authentication system?

Tags: vb.net, authentication, qr-code, two-factor-authentication

**I am only doing this as a method to secure a third party product that does not have a native way of requesting and setting up 2FA. Essentially this creates a request that is sent to IT to have them manually add the secret key to a users profile when requested.**

How should I generate a "secret" code for my two factor authentication system?

I'm using the [QRCoder package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QRCoder/) to generate a nice displayable QR Code for my userbase. And it works great in the Microsoft Authenticator app, but both [Authy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmrCP.jpg) and [Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTKIF.jpg) fail.

I suppose my random secret generator function is to blame?

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim generator As OneTimePassword = New OneTimePassword() With {
      .Secret = GenerateRandomString(16),
      .Issuer = "My Site",
      .Label = "My Service",
      .Type = OneTimePassword.OneTimePasswordAuthType.TOTP
  }

        Dim payload As String = generator.ToString()
        Dim qrGenerator As QRCodeGenerator = New QRCodeGenerator()
        Dim qrCodeData As QRCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(payload, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q)
        Dim qrCode As QRCode = New QRCode(qrCodeData)

        LiteralQRCode.Text = generator.Secret

        Dim imgBarCode As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image()
        imgBarCode.Height = 300
        imgBarCode.Width = 300
        Using bitMap As Bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20)
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                Dim byteImage As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
                imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage)
            End Using
            plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode)
        End Using

    End Sub

    Public Function GenerateRandomString(ByRef iLength As Integer) As String
        Dim rdm As New Random()
        Dim allowChrs() As Char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()
        Dim sResult As String = ""

        For i As Integer = 0 To iLength - 1
            sResult += allowChrs(rdm.Next(0, allowChrs.Length))
        Next

        Return sResult
    End Function
```

Comment: I'd recommend one of the dozen of libraries that already exist, implementing security critical stuff yourself is generally a bad idea unless you know what you are doing. If you still want to implement it yourself follow the security guidelines of the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238#section-5.1

Comment: Normally, I'd agree, but this is basically being used in a request form to have the "secret" key setup in a third party application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [OtpNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Otp.NET) and using their Base32Encode function to get what I needed.

Hopefully this will help the next person who is attempting to work on a project that isn't exactly conventional.

```
Dim totp = KeyGeneration.GenerateRandomKey()

Dim generator As OneTimePassword = New OneTimePassword() With {
              .Secret = Base32Encoding.ToString(totp),
              .Issuer = "My Site",
              .Label = "My Service",
              .Type = OneTimePassword.OneTimePasswordAuthType.TOTP
          }
```

Comment: I'm think about to add TOTP to an app and want to use Microsoft Authentificator on the client side. For me, the server side is not clear. As far as I understand for every user a different secret has to be generated and then be used for verification at runtime. So... I think, the secret has to be stored in the (own) user database? It seems, as you do this with OtpNet. But this only should work, if the SAME secret is generated from the MS Authentification app at runtime -> I don' see the link to the "MS universe"... How does this work in practice? Thanks for a feedback.